# The “Button” control is not showing up in the Toolbox in a .NET Core project

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Recently I update my Visual Studio 2019 to the latest version and create Windows Forms application in .NET Core 3.1 (not preview version).

In the form design toolbox I can not find button control but other controls are on the list.

I used to search for it on the top of the list(Toolbox) but could not find Button control.

What's wrong? Should I reset or install something?

Sorted alphabetically:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding one manually in code?

Comment: @JonasH manually, yes it works

Comment: For this issue, you can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).

Comment: You're also missing the CheckBox and CheckedListBox. It can (still) happen when you update VS. Close VS, clear the Toolbox cache *manually* from `[Disc]:\Users\[Current User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0...` (`privateregistry.bin` and friends, `toolbox[...]`). Reopen VS and see whether those controls reappear.

Comment: See also the `Known issue` note [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/). Apply what's in the previous comment in case resetting the Toolbox is not enough.